# Highcharts x axis label position is on top of graph

Tags: highcharts

I have a highcharts chart that is rendered dynamically on the page and also rendered to a headless browser that screenshots it for inclusion in a pdf report.  The two charts use identical options, but the x axis labels in the headless version appear on top of the chart.

Dynamic version:
[highcharts example with correct x axis label position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irk2t.png)

Headless (wrong) version:
[highcharts example with incorrect x axis label position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCr4t.png)

Is there any way to specify the position of the x axis labels?  The tickmark positions are correct and highcharts is correctly spacing the datetime data.  I just can't figure out why the headless version has the labels moving vertically up until they are on top of the chart.

xAxis options:

```
xAxis: {
    title: {
      text: "Date"
    },
    crosshair: false,
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      day: "%m/%d/%y",
      month: "%m",
      year: "%Y"
    },
    labels: {
      rotation: -60
    },
    type: "datetime",
    units: [
      ['day', [1, 2]],
      ['month', [1, 2]],
      ['year', [1]]
    ],
  }
```

Thanks!

**EDITED**

This only happens when there are many data points with a datetime present.  If there are only a few data points, the two charts look identical.

Comment: Hi opticbob_dev, Maybe this problem is caused by animation? Please try to disable chart animation. To change label position, you can use label `x` and `y` properties: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.y

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, I disabled the chart animation and the `plotOptions.series.animation` but neither had an effect.  The label `x` and `y` properties worked perfectly on the example I provided above.  I then tried it on a data set with only a 3 data points and my labels are now below and to the left of where they should be.  The tickmarks always remain where they should be in respect to the data points.  It seems like `x` and `y` do not strictly position the label in respect to the tickmark.  Does their behavior change when the chart overflows with labels?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi opticbob_dev, It's a very strange problem and looks like a bug. Please try to use the code from this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/78vxzhmg/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, Sorry I have been so late to respond to this.  Our version of Highcharts (4.2.x) doesn't have the `chart.events.render` function yet.  I'm going to upgrade our Highcharts and try the code from your jsfiddle again.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi opticbob_dev, the update itself can fix your problem. Anyway please let me know if your problem has been resolved.